# Why am I getting an error trying to create related records usingPrisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

When trying to create a new user and a new company connected to it I am getting the following error log:

error - Error:
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

{
data: {
email: 'x',
hashedPassword: 'x',
company: {
create: {
name: 'x',
gender: 'x',
firstName: 'x',
lastName: 'x',
street: 'x',
houseNumber: 'x',
postcode: 'x',
city: 'x',
country: 'x',
countryCode: 'x',
callNumber: 'x',
emailAddress: 'x',
website: 'x',
socials: 'x',
companyUser: {
~~~~~~~~~~~
connect: {
id: ''
}
}
}
}
},
include: {
company: true
}
}

Unknown arg `companyUser` in data.company.create.companyUser for type CompanyCreateWithoutCompanyUserInput. Did you mean `gender`? Available args:
type CompanyCreateWithoutCompanyUserInput {
name: String
gender: String
firstName: String
lastName: String
street: String
houseNumber: String
postcode: String
city: String
country: String
countryCode: String
callNumber: String
emailAddress: String
website?: String | Null
socials?: String | Null
}

This are the schemas:

```
model User {
  id             String    @id @default(cuid())
  name           String?
  email          String    @unique
  emailVerified  DateTime?
  hashedPassword String
  role           Role      @default(USER)
  image          String?
  accounts       Account[]
  sessions       Session[]
  company        Company?
}

model Company {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String  @unique
  gender        String
  firstName     String
  lastName      String
  street        String
  houseNumber   String
  postcode      String
  city          String
  country       String
  countryCode   String
  callNumber    String
  emailAddress  String
  website       String?
  socials       String?
  companyUser   User    @relation(fields: [companyUserId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  companyUserId String  @unique
}
```

And this is the query which caused the error to be thrown:

```
 const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        ...userInfo,
        company: {
          create: companyInfo
        }
      },
      include: {
        company: true
      }
    })
```

Here is what is contained in the userInfo and companyInfo:

```
      userInfo: {
        email: 'x',
        password: 'x'
      }

      companyInfo: {
        companyName: 'x',
        gender: 'x',
        firstName: 'x',
        lastName: 'x',
        street: 'x',
        houseNumber: 'x',
        postcode: 'x',
        city: 'x',
        country: 'x',
        countryCode: 'x',
        callNumber: 'x',
        emailAddress: 'x',
        website: 'x',
        socials: 'x'
      }
```

And here is the example of the Prisma documentation that I was following:

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    email: 'elsa@prisma.io',
    name: 'Elsa Prisma',
    posts: {
      create: [
        { title: 'How to make an omelette' },
        { title: 'How to eat an omelette' },
      ],
    },
  },
  include: {
    posts: true, // Include all posts in the returned object
  },
})
```

and here is the link to that part of the docs:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-related-record

Comment: What is in companyInfo?

Comment: userInfo: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }

      companyInfo: {
        companyName: '',
        gender: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        street: '',
        houseNumber: '',
        postcode: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        countryCode: '',
        callNumber: '',
        emailAddress: '',
        website: '',
        socials: ''
      }

Comment: Try to remove companyUser: { connect: { id: '' } }. prisma should connect them automatically with nested creates. No need to connect them twice

Comment: I never added that. I think the error log is just showing what it is doing in the background.

Comment: Can you update the question with both userInfo and companyInfo. it is hard to see what is going on

Comment: I really can't figure this one out. Dunno why prisma would append another connect there. Try to do it in reverse. Create a company first with nested user create. Also check if you generated the latest prisma changes (npx prisma migrate dev / npx prisma generate). maybe some changes didn't propagate.

Comment: Could it also have to do with the Prisma version or are nested create statements available since early versions?

Comment: Which version are you on?

Comment: I am using version 3.11.0.

Comment: They had nested writes in v3. Well, No idea how to help. Try the following: Triple check that you are forwarding correct data, triple check that your schema is up to date, maybe the   "companyUserId String  unique" is causing issues? Try  "companyUserId Int" without "unique" and Int instead of String. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it reversed as you recommended and it worked even though it is absolutely unintuitive. Thank you very much for your efforts.